# Grouping by date, with 0 when count() yields no lines

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by

I'm using Postgresql 9 and I'm fighting with counting and grouping when no lines are counted.

Let's assume the following schema :

```
create table views {
 date_event timestamp with time zone ;
 event_id integer;
}
```

Let's imagine the following content :

```
2012-01-01 00:00:05    2
2012-01-01 01:00:05    5
2012-01-01 03:00:05    8
2012-01-01 03:00:15    20
```

I want to group by hour, and count the number of lines. I wish I could retrieve the following :

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00    1
2012-01-01 01:00:00    1
2012-01-01 02:00:00    0
2012-01-01 03:00:00    2
2012-01-01 04:00:00    0
2012-01-01 05:00:00    0
.
.

2012-01-07 23:00:00    0
```

I mean that for each time range slot, I count the number of lines in my table whose date correspond, otherwise, I return a line with a count at zero.

The following will definitely not work (will yeld only lines with counted lines > 0).

```
SELECT  extract ( hour from date_event ),count(*)
FROM views
where date_event > '2012-01-01' and date_event <'2012-01-07'
GROUP BY extract ( hour from date_event );
```

Please note I might also need to group by minute, or by hour, or by day, or by month, or by year (multiple queries is possible of course).

I can only use plain old sql, and since my views table can be very big (>100M records), I try to keep performance in mind.

How can this be achieved ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given that you don't have the dates in the table, you need a way to generate them. You can use the [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) function:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2012-01-01'::timestamp, '2012-01-07 23:00', '1 hour') AS ts;
```

This will produce results like this:

```
         ts          
---------------------
 2012-01-01 00:00:00
 2012-01-01 01:00:00
 2012-01-01 02:00:00
 2012-01-01 03:00:00
...
 2012-01-07 21:00:00
 2012-01-07 22:00:00
 2012-01-07 23:00:00
(168 rows)
```

The remaining task is to join the two selects using an outer join like this :

```
select extract ( day from ts ) as day, extract ( hour from ts ) as hour,coalesce(count,0) as count from 
(
    SELECT  extract ( day from date ) as day , extract ( hour from date ) as hr ,count(*)
    FROM    sr
    where date>'2012-01-01' and date <'2012-01-07'
    GROUP BY   extract ( day from date ) , extract ( hour from date )
) AS cnt 
 right outer join ( SELECT * FROM generate_series ( '2012-01-01'::timestamp, '2012-01-07 23:00', '1 hour') AS ts ) as dtetable on extract ( hour from ts ) = cnt.hr and extract ( day from ts ) = cnt.day 
 order by day,hour asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the output what your are looking for,

```
select to_char(date_event, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00') as time, count (to_char(date_event, 'HH24:00')) as count from views where date(date_event) > '2012-01-01' and date(date_event) > '2012-01-07' group by time order by time;
```

Comment: Thanks Vinesh. However this doesn't work (timestamp at 0 are not yielded), and the > and < should be >= and <=.

Comment: This is wrong answer. This doesn answer the question asked.